# Correct/Optimized way to reschedule a Java task in a ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, threadpool

Suppose that we have a Java Task (*e.g.:* `Runnable`) that will be executed if we do not receive an external signal in `x` seconds.

A common way to solve this problem is to use a schedule thread pool (such as `ScheduledExecutorService`) to execute this task considering `x` delay. When we receive that external event, from other part of the system, we need to reschedule this task, that is, to reinsert this task in the thread pool with `x`  delay.

My question is: what is the correct/optimized way to reschedule a task in a `ScheduleExecutorService`? Current solutions usually focus on removing/canceling and reinserting the dealyed task in the thread pool. Is this the best approach?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too heavily about "optimized" unless you have profiled and know this is causing trouble.  Seems easiest to just keep a reference to the previous task you did, cancel it, and schedule a new one replacing the old reference.  What other sort of approach would you have in mind?

Comment: Googling for "debouncing" seems to indicate people doing the same thing, btw.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723112/cancelling-method-calls-when-the-same-method-is-called-multiple-time

Comment: @JoshBerry, yep the profile show that the main issue in our code is the cancel/insert of task in the scheduler. I will take a look in 'debouncing'.

Comment: I'm impressed that something like this could be eating your time.  What sort of timeframe are we talking here?  You might be better off putting a simple test for tolerance in rescheduling.  For example, instead of always cancelling and rescheduling, you can make it so that every X interval you just leave it on the currently scheduled task.  This really depends on some of the numbers we are talking about, though.

Comment: So, yeah, how often are we talking about getting these events?  How important is the X seconds after the last event?  You could alternatively setup an event that runs in X seconds and checks a flag when it awakens.  If it is beyond X, run the task, otherwise schedule for a task to run for the delta.