# Grails - Implement Debounce Algorithm for AutoComplete Request in Controller

Tags: java, servlets, grails, groovy, request

In Grails, I have the following code snippet.

```
class AutoCompleteController {
   def getAutoCompleteData() {
       // Open db connection and get the data
       // and do other long and heavy computation
       jsonString(data: result)
   }
}
```

I want to implement a **debounce** algorithm for any incoming request if it comes from **the same user, the same request data, and the same user's IP address**.

I have been looking at [implementing debounce in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742210/implementing-debounce-in-java) However, I don't have any idea how to integrating it with my grails controller.

Please help me how to implement it in grails? I am looking for implementation with java annotation something like this:

```
class AutoCompleteController {
   @Debounce(delay = 1000) // ------------>>>>>> How to implement this annotation?
   def getAutoCompleteData() {
       // heavy logic
       jsonString(data: result)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the last request data hash into the `session` and compare it to the actual data. The simplest approach would be:

```
def getAutoCompleteData() {
   int hash = hashTheRelevantParams()
   if( null == session.cache ) session.cache = [:]
   def result = session.cache[ hash ] ?: getResultTheHardWay() 
   session.cache.clear()
   session.cache[ hash ] = result
   jsonString(data: result)
}
```

If the thing should be used in many locations, pack it into a `controller interceptor` or a `filter`. If you need the timeout-driven cache, add a timestampt into your data, that is stored in the session or use some smart caching solution, like [Google's Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for. Your answer will just add more complexity in my current implementation. In addition, your answer is not the way how debounce algorithm works!